# Regular expression to perform following operation

Tags: regex, regular-language

Input string contains multiple `key[with some value]`, which we need to replace with `key[with some value],val[value which is same as key]`.

Input string:

```
...key[102]...key[108]... key[211]...
```

Output string:

```
... key[102],val[102]...key[108],val[108]...key[211],val[211]...
```

Basically I need to replace all the key with values inside square braces with `key[value],val[same value]`.

E.g. `key[102]` → `key[102],val[102]`, and `key[108]` → `key[108],val[108]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use capturing groups.( http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html )

```
key\[(.*?)\]
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/PPJSTK5IK7A58mO3)

Example java code (i couldn't test it):

```
var str = "...key[102]...key[108]... key[211]...";
System.out.println( (str.replaceAll("key\\[(.*?)\\]", "key[$1],val[$1]") );
```